# hibernate SELECT..WHERE.. IN (value1, val2...)

Tags: java, hibernate

when using createCriteria, how to specify  SELECT..WHERE.. IN (value1, val2...) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Restrictions.in](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-narrowing):

```
List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add( Restrictions.in( "name", new String[] { "Fritz", "Izi", "Pk" } ) )
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Restrictions.in](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#in) method.